# What's the easiest way to download DataTables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I was looking at https://datatables.net/manual/installation on the various methods to install `DataTables` and the one using `bower` looked the simplest to me. So I tried installing bower first using `npm`

```
npm install bower
```

But I got these warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.4: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/.bin/semver as it wasn't installed by /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/semver
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/.bin/nopt as it wasn't installed by /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/nopt
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp as it wasn't installed by /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/.bin/browserslist as it wasn't installed by         /Users/biju/workspace/rails/movie_db/node_modules/browserslist
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
+ bower@1.8.4
added 1 package and removed 1100 packages in 14.042s
```

Finally the above step did NOT instal `bower` and when I ran bower to install datatbles:

```
bower install --save datatables.net
```

I got this error:

```
-bash: bower: command not found
```

I was wondering if `bower` is deprecated and been replaced by `yarn`, then why does the `datatables` website show instructions on how to install the same using `yarn`?

Any tips on the way to install DataTables using the minimum number of steps?

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean "broken."  It simply means that someday you may not be able to do it this way anymore.

Comment: Oh.  Well, you didn't say that before.  Soooo.... What prevents you from simply using one of the other methods for installation?

Comment: I don't understand them completely. For example, the NPM approach talks about `browserify` - should I install that as well? And that approach also lists these 2 lines - `var $  = require( 'jquery' );
var dt = require( 'datatables.net' )();` - I didn't quite get where I should place these 2 lines? in `application.js`?  Sorry about the basic questions; which approach would you recommend (and which one has the fewest steps)?

Comment: I have no idea.  Perhaps you should try the one that looks the simplest from your remaining alternatives.  That's how you picked Bower.

Comment: Isn't the CDN option the easiest?

Comment: The CDN option seems the easiest - yes - looks like the CDN server already hosts everything we need and we just need to include these 2 lines in our code to be able to use them directly off of the CDN servers - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>`. My question is - these 2 lines - where do they go? Do they both go in the same file? or in separate files?

Comment: ok - I tried the CDN approach. But I don't get a datatable on my page. Using the above 2 lines and using this script in your view - `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );` - is that not enough? What am I missing here? The DataTables website says these 2 steps are enough

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use this gem?
https://github.com/mkhairi/jquery-datatables

Comment: this sounds straight forward! Thanks much! I will try this today and get back!

Comment: I tried using this gem but I get errors while installing the same. The error I get was reported long back in https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/issues/143 and the author of the gem commented it was fixed; but another user commented in Feb '18 that he still has the issue (which I face too) and he did not receive any reply. I have opened a new ticket for this issue - https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/issues/232. but going by this ticket, https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/issues/229 the users seem to believe this gem is dead now!!